# numpy / ipython error with np.set_printoptions when loading ipython

Tags: python, numpy, ipython, conda

I don't know if this is a problem with python, ipython or numpy but I can't figure it out.

I have a conda environment that works perfectly fine on a development server.

When I install the same environment on our HPC and launch ipython I get the following:

```
Python 3.7.8 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Jul 31 2020, 02:25:08) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 5.8.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-98a05c4d41bc> in <module>()
----> 1 np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.NaN, precision=3, suppress=True, linewidth=180)

/blah/envs/py3_hpc_ml/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/arrayprint.py in set_printoptions(precision, threshold, edgeitems, linewidth, suppress, nanstr, infstr, formatter, sign, floatmode, legacy)
    243     opt = _make_options_dict(precision, threshold, edgeitems, linewidth,
    244                              suppress, nanstr, infstr, sign, formatter,
--> 245                              floatmode, legacy)
    246     # formatter is always reset
    247     opt['formatter'] = formatter

/blah/envs/py3_hpc_ml/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/arrayprint.py in _make_options_dict(precision, threshold, edgeitems, linewidth, suppress, nanstr, infstr, sign, formatter, floatmode, legacy)
     84             raise TypeError("threshold must be numeric")
     85         if np.isnan(threshold):
---> 86             raise ValueError("threshold must be non-NAN, try "
     87                              "sys.maxsize for untruncated representation")
     88     return options

ValueError: threshold must be non-NAN, try sys.maxsize for untruncated representation
```

I've tried cloning my working environment, making a new one from scratch, etc and I keep getting the same issue.

If I start on the HPC with a different (working) environment, as soon as I upgrade numpy it goes wrong and stops working.

Comment: Where does the `np.set_printoptions` command come from? Are you inserting it manually or do you have set up startup commands for IPython (somewhere in `~/.ipython/profile_default/startup`)?

Comment: I've never added anything to a startup file (that dir is blank aside from a readme). I assumed that command was some kind of initialisation that ipython does automatically?

Comment: This problem has been solved in
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54386460/installed-face-recognition-but-cannot-import-python3-64

Comment: I wouldn't consider that solved to be honest. There's obviously a work-around (by setting the option after you receive the error) but I was more interested in understanding why it was happening and stopping it from happening at all so it doesn't generate that error message every time I load ipython.